# Django Internationalization gives Internal Error when Debug is False Only when 500.html is present

Tags: python, django, internal-server-error, django-i18n

I enable Django Internationalization in my app, and it works fine even when debug is False. But recently I tried providing 500.html and 404.html for my server error and page not found errors.

Now the app gives "`Internal Error: /`" when you visit homepage. example `localhost:8000` would give you Server Error. But if I manually Enter the Url like `localhost:8000/en/` it works fine.

Below are the errors it provides on traceback:

```html
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:40] DEBUG [django.template:872] Exception while resolving variable 'LANGUAGES' in template '500.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 558, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>], [<URLResolver <module 'accounts.urls' from '/home/trans/Documents/my_app/freight_app/accounts/urls.py'> (None:None) '^profile-accounts/admin/'>], [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'en/'>]], 'path': ''}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 108, in get_exception_response
    response = callback(request, **{**param_dict, 'exception': exception})
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 49, in page_not_found
    body = template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 192, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/freight_app/administration/templatetags/custom_admin_tags.py", line 16, in change_lang
    url_parts = resolve(path)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 24, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 558, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>], [<URLResolver <module 'accounts.urls' from '/home/trans/Documents/my_app/freight_app/accounts/urls.py'> (None:None) '^profile-accounts/admin/'>], [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'en/'>]], 'path': ''}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'LANGUAGES'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 835, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
AttributeError: type object 'Context' has no attribute 'LANGUAGES'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'LANGUAGES'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [LANGUAGES] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}]
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:40] DEBUG [django.template:872] Exception while resolving variable 'request' in template '500.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 558, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>], [<URLResolver <module 'accounts.urls' from '/home/trans/Documents/my_app/freight_app/accounts/urls.py'> (None:None) '^profile-accounts/admin/'>], [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'en/'>]], 'path': ''}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 108, in get_exception_response
    response = callback(request, **{**param_dict, 'exception': exception})
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 49, in page_not_found
    body = template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 192, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/freight_app/administration/templatetags/custom_admin_tags.py", line 16, in change_lang
    url_parts = resolve(path)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 24, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 558, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>], [<URLResolver <module 'accounts.urls' from '/home/trans/Documents/my_app/freight_app/accounts/urls.py'> (None:None) '^profile-accounts/admin/'>], [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'en/'>]], 'path': ''}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'request'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 835, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
AttributeError: type object 'Context' has no attribute 'request'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'request'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trans/Documents/my_app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [request] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}]
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:41] ERROR [django.request:228] Internal Server Error: /
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:41] ERROR [django.server:154] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 10352
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:41] INFO [django.server:154] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 8192
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:42] INFO [django.server:154] "GET /en/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:42] INFO [django.server:154] "GET /static/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 8192
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:42] INFO [django.server:154] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 8192
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:42] INFO [django.server:154] "GET /static/images/500.png HTTP/1.1" 200 39523
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:42] INFO [django.server:154] "GET /static/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 8192
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:43] INFO [django.server:154] "GET /static/images/ajax-loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 8192
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:43] INFO [django.server:154] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150
[10/Jul/2020 09:49:43] INFO [django.server:154] "HEAD /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `prefix_default_language=False,` inside `i18n_patterns` stopped the error. Although now the url `localhost:8000` doesn't redirect to `localhost:8000/en/` when visited, but it works fine.

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
     path('', view.Home, name="Home"),
     prefix_default_language=False,
)
```